# Complex annulus without the real positive ray is simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Let $$A=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}|1<|z|<2\}.$$Put $G=A\setminus \{a+i0|a\ge 0\}$. Show that $G$ is simply connected.

Our definition of simply connected is a domain $B\subset \mathbb{C}$ where for any two paths $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ in $B$ with the same starting point $a$ and the same ending point $b$ there exists a homotopy $$H:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to B,$$ such that $$H(0,t)=\gamma_0(t),H(1,t)=\gamma_1(t),\quad t\in [0,1]$$and $$H(s,0)=a,H(s,1)=b,\quad s\in [0,1].$$

I'm not sure how to show this. First of all I have to find two paths for two given points in $G$ with the same end and starting point. Let $z_0=r_0e^{i\theta_0}$ and $z=re^{i\theta}$ be elements in $G$ and consider the paths $$\gamma_1(t)=\begin{cases} (r(1-2t)+r_02t)e^{i\theta},\quad t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}],\\ r_0e^{i(\theta(2-2t)+\theta_0|\cos(\pi t)|},\quad t\in [\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases}$$and
$$\gamma_2(t)=\begin{cases}(r(1-2t)r_02t)e^{i\theta},\quad t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}],\\r_0e^{i(\theta|\sin(\pi t)|+\theta_0|\cos(\pi t)|},\quad t\in [\frac{1}{2},1].\end{cases}$$Then $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are two paths starting at $z$ and ending at $z_0$ and contained in $G$. However I'm not sure how to proceed and if this is even the correct way. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Every contractible space is simply connected. Can you show that $G$ is contractible?

Comment: Picking two paths won't help you, since you have to show it for *all* pairs of paths with same start and end points!

Comment: You need to do more than just find two paths and show they are homotopic: you need to show that *no matter which paths are chosen*, there exists a homotopy regardless. I think the switch to polar coordinates should provide a homeomorphism from $A$ to the rectangle $(1, 2) \times(0,2\pi).$ I don't have the time to try to flesh this out into a full argument right now, but I'm leaving this comment to encourage you to think about this approach.

Comment: @Christoph So to show a space is contractible I have to show that there exists $H:[0,1]\times G\to G$ such that $H(0,z)=z$ for $z\in G$, $H(\lambda,z_0)=z_0,\lambda \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Instead of proving the simply-connectedness from the definition, I'd suggest you use its homeomorphism invariance: if you find a conformal mapping of it to the disc, G is simply connected (and the Riemann mapping theorem assures you the existence of the mapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the map
\begin{align*}
\Phi\colon (1,2)\times(0,2\pi) &\longrightarrow G, \\
(r,\theta) &\longmapsto r\, e^{i\theta}.
\end{align*}
Can you show that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I' not quite sure how this would help. Our definition definition of contractible is that there exists a continuous function $H:[0,1]\times G\to G$ such that $H(0,z)=z$ for $z\in G, H(\lambda,z_0)=z_0,\lambda\in [0,1],H(1,z)=z_0$ for all $z\in G$. This is a introductory course to complex analysis and we have not yet defined what a homeomorphism is. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you find such a map $H\colon[0,1]\times X\to X$ for $X=(1,2)\times (0,2\pi)$, which should be easy, then $(t,z)\mapsto \Phi(H(t,\Phi^{-1}(z))$ is such a map for $G$.

Comment: Hey again, I have been trying to find that map $H$ but I'm having some trouble with it. Do you mind throwing a hint my way? Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to show that it is contractible! Thank you!